# How do I connect to a external game controller in swift - apple tv

Tags: swift, apple-tv, gamecontroller

I have followed this tutorial here: https://cartoonsmart.com/how-to-support-external-game-controllers-with-swift-2-and-sprite-kit-for-the-new-apple-tv/ to connect a external game controller to the apple tv in sprite kit, but I was unable to do it with the tutorials code. I was getting no error message, but it simply was not working. Here is my code:

```
func setUpControllerObservers() {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(connectControllers), name: NSNotification.Name.GCControllerDidConnect, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(disconnectController), name: NSNotification.Name.GCControllerDidDisconnect, object: nil)
}

func connectControllers() {
    var count = 0
    for controller in GCController.controllers() {
        count = count + 1
        print(count)
        print(controller.extendedGamepad != nil)
        print(controller.microGamepad != nil)
        print(controller.gamepad != nil)
        if (controller.extendedGamepad != nil && controller.playerIndex == .indexUnset) {
            if (count == 1) {
                controller.playerIndex = .index1
            }
            else if (count == 2) {
                controller.playerIndex = .index2
            }
            else if (count == 3) {
                controller.playerIndex = .index3
            }
            else if (count == 4) {
                controller.playerIndex = .index4
            }
            controller.extendedGamepad?.valueChangedHandler = nil
            setupExtendedController(controller: controller)
        }
    }
}

func disconnectController() {

}

func setupExtendedController(controller: GCController) {
    controller.extendedGamepad?.valueChangedHandler = { (gamepad: GCExtendedGamepad, element: GCControllerElement) in
        // not calling
    }
}
```

When debugging, I found the `GCController.controllers()` array to be empty, even though it was connected to the apple tv. To be extra sure, I even tested the controller on a app from the app store which worked fine. Can anyone help please?

**Edit:** here is my didMove function:

```
didMove(to view: SKView) {
    setUpControllerObservers()
    connectControllers()
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When and from which class is your `setUpControllerObservers` function called? We need some more context to help you out.

Anyway, make sure you manually call your `connectControllers` function at least once yourself. You can't solely rely on the incoming notification to call that function for you. They mention this in the tutorial you have linked:

> Notice too, **we are calling connectControllers ourselves right after
>   setUpControllerObservers.** The first time the app runs,
>   setUpControllerObservers will cause our NSNotification to also call
>   connectControllers, but if we were to go back and forth between our
>   GameScene and other class, we can’t rely on connectControllers getting
>   called again from the notification. Which is why we call it ourselves.

- From your linked tutorial on [CartoonSmart](https://cartoonsmart.com/how-to-support-external-game-controllers-with-swift-2-and-sprite-kit-for-the-new-apple-tv/)

You should also make sure you don't call these functions before your app has finished launching (e.g. early in the `AppDelegate`):

> Call the controllers class method to retrieve an array of GCController objects
>   for all connected controllers. [...] If there are no
>   connected controllers or you **call this method while your app is
>   launching, the array will be empty**.

- From Apple's [Game Controller Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/ServicesDiscovery/Conceptual/GameControllerPG/DiscoveringControllers/DiscoveringControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013276-CH2-SW1) (Finding Connected Controllers)

---

**Edit:**

For debugging purposes, could you try 'discovering' the controller using the `startWirelessControllerDiscovery(completionHandler:)` function? (described in [Game Controller Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/ServicesDiscovery/Conceptual/GameControllerPG/DiscoveringControllers/DiscoveringControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013276-CH2-SW1): Discovering Wireless Controllers)

Comment: I edited my question, It was called from the didMove function, and my didmove to view function is given in the question now

Comment: Thanks. Could you try 'discovering' the controller? See edit above.

Comment: In my case, the **disconnectControllers** Selector is **never** called whether I call it in my **didMove** func or in my ViewController’s **viewDidLoad()** func.